# Apache Camel: Help in understanding usage of SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

Anybody has experience or know how to use SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy to manage a scheduler at runtime? To change the scheduler timing, suspend or resume. I tried using this in a spring boot project but it is not working as documented. Below is my Route configuration and a Test class I used to test this.

```
@Component
public class MyRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRouter.class);


    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy simpleScheduledRoutePolicy = new SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000l;
        simpleScheduledRoutePolicy.setRouteStartDate(new Date(startTime));
        simpleScheduledRoutePolicy.setRouteStartRepeatInterval(3000l);
        simpleScheduledRoutePolicy.setRouteStartRepeatCount(3);

        from("direct:myroute")
                .routeId("myroute")
                .routePolicy(simpleScheduledRoutePolicy)
                .autoStartup(true)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, logger, "myroute invoked")
                .to("mock:test");
    }
}
```

Test class code

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyRouterTest {

    @Autowired
    private CamelContext camelContext;

    @EndpointInject("mock:test")
    MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    public void myRouteIsScheduledSuccessfully() {
        resultEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(2);
        Thread.sleep(7000);
        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

}
```

But I just gets below logs saying the scheduler started but it is not triggering every 3 seconds as configured in policy. 
I tried to invoke the direct component from test method, still not working. Not sure where I am going wrong.

```
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:17.928 [main] MyRouterTest - Starting MyRouterTest on PPC11549 with PID 20892 (started by rmr in C:\Data\Telenet\Workspaces\atoms-event-engine)
[DEBUG] 2020-04-17 15:22:17.930 [main] MyRouterTest - Running with Spring Boot v2.2.6.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.5.RELEASE
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:17.932 [main] MyRouterTest - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:19.634 [main] RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:19.679 [main] RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 36ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:20.226 [main] PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration' of type [org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:20.848 [main] HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:21.437 [main] HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:22.602 [main] LRUCacheFactory - Detected and using LURCacheFactory: camel-caffeine-lrucache
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:24.082 [main] JobRepositoryFactoryBean - No database type set, using meta data indicating: H2
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:24.120 [main] SimpleJobLauncher - No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:24.485 [main] ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:24.695 [main] SpringBootRoutesCollector - Loading additional Camel XML routes from: classpath:camel/*.xml
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:24.698 [main] SpringBootRoutesCollector - Loading additional Camel XML rests from: classpath:camel-rest/*.xml
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:24.727 [main] MyRouterTest - Started MyRouterTest in 7.338 seconds (JVM running for 11.356)
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:24.729 [main] JobLauncherCommandLineRunner - Running default command line with: []
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:24.734 [main] CamelAnnotationsHandler - Setting shutdown timeout to [10 SECONDS] on CamelContext with name [camelContext].
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:24.815 [main] CamelSpringBootExecutionListener - @RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class) before: class com.telenet.atoms.eventengine.camel.MyRouterTest.myRouteIsScheduledSuccessfully
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:24.817 [main] CamelSpringBootExecutionListener - Initialized CamelSpringBootRunner now ready to start CamelContext
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:24.818 [main] CamelAnnotationsHandler - Starting CamelContext with name [camelContext].
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:24.902 [main] DefaultManagementStrategy - JMX is enabled
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.308 [main] AbstractCamelContext - Apache Camel 3.2.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.438 [main] QuartzComponent - Create and initializing scheduler.
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.442 [main] QuartzComponent - Setting org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export=true to ensure QuartzScheduler(s) will be enlisted in JMX.
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.483 [main] StdSchedulerFactory - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.487 [main] SimpleThreadPool - Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: main
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.511 [main] SchedulerSignalerImpl - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.511 [main] QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.516 [main] RAMJobStore - RAMJobStore initialized.
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.528 [main] QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel-1' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.528 [main] StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel-1' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.528 [main] StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.529 [main] AbstractCamelContext - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.623 [main] AbstractCamelContext - Route: myroute started and consuming from: direct://myroute
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.625 [main] AbstractCamelContext - Route: orderfault started and consuming from: direct://orderfault
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.637 [main] AbstractCamelContext - Total 2 routes, of which 2 are started
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.638 [main] AbstractCamelContext - Apache Camel 3.2.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.329 seconds
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.663 [main] ScheduledRoutePolicy - Scheduled trigger: triggerGroup-myroute.trigger-START-myroute for action: START on route myroute
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.663 [main] ScheduledRoutePolicy - Scheduled trigger: triggerGroup-orderfault.trigger-START-orderfault for action: START on route orderfault
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.664 [main] QuartzComponent - Starting scheduler.
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:25.665 [main] QuartzScheduler - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel-1_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:33.101 [main] MockEndpoint - Asserting: mock://test is satisfied
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:43.134 [main] MyRouterTest - ********************************************************************************
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:43.135 [main] MyRouterTest - Testing done: myRouteIsScheduledSuccessfully(com.telenet.atoms.eventengine.camel.MyRouterTest)
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:43.136 [main] MyRouterTest - Took: 17.469 seconds (17469 millis)
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:43.136 [main] MyRouterTest - ********************************************************************************
[INFO ] 2020-04-17 15:22:43.137 [main] CamelSpringBootExecutionListener - @RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class) after: class com.telenet.atoms.eventengine.camel.MyRouterTest.myRouteIsScheduledSuccessfully

java.lang.AssertionError: mock://test Received message count. Expected: <2> but was: <0>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy`](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/simplescheduledroutepolicy.html) works as expected - it starts your Camel Route and that's what it is for: starting and stopping routes.

Because of your test, I guess that you want to have a Scheduler endpoint that triggers messages in a configured interval. For this you have to use [Camel Timer](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/timer-component.html), [Camel Scheduler](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/scheduler-component.html) or [Camel Quartz](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/quartz-component.html).

Since **your route does not contain any of these**, there is simply no scheduler that can be started.

To create a scheduler that (after waiting initially 5 seconds) fires every 3 seconds you can use for example this:

```
from("scheduler://foo?initialDelay=5s&delay=3s")...
```

**Change at runtime** (added due to comment)

The [Camel Quartz](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/quartz-component.html) component obviously uses the Quartz scheduler and Quartz provides a JMX access. So if you want to change the scheduler this is probably your best option.

To start and stop routes at runtime you should have a look at [Camel Controlbus](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/controlbus-component.html).

Comment: My requirement is a scheduler but I wanted to control it at runtime by changing the frequency, suspend, resume etc. I thought I could do it by SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy. The examples in camel site (https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/simplescheduledroutepolicy.html) have route starting from a direct component and the policy is assigned, similar to my example. But by that way my scheduler is not even starting. So I couldnt understand

Comment: These examples you mention do not contain any scheduler, and the same applies for your route. So whatever you do with these routes, there can be no scheduler starting because it does not exist. You only get a scheduler if you use one of the three components I mention. See my extended answer for runtime changes.

Comment: The examples given in the camel site also uses no scheduler but the policy is applied on a direct component, so how should I interpret those examples..

Comment: The examples on [this Camel page](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/simplescheduledroutepolicy.html) just start the Camel Direct Route. The route itself does nothing at all apart from routing an incoming message to a Mock endpoint. The `RepeatCount` and `RepeatInterval` settings are to **start the route** in a given interval.

Comment: The route does nothing, but it should get invoked as per the repeat count and repeat interval right. This is not happening. I  noticed it get invoked only once when you start the application or call the route from another route. Is the route getting automatically triggered as many times per the policy in your case?

Comment: OK, we have to separate two things here: 1. Route start and stop. These are things that happen automatically if you do nothing. All Camel routes are started on application start and all routes are stopped on application shutdown. However, you can start and stop routes during runtime, too. For this you can use a `ScheduledRoutePolicy`. It starts or stops your route based on time conditions. That is what the mentioned examples do. They start the route once (`RepeatCount` = 1) 3 seconds after the Policy is created (`startTime`). The `RepeatInterval` of 3 seconds does nothing because no repetition

Comment: 2. Route processing. This is the work the route has to do and is implemented by the route. This **does not happen through `ScheduledRoutePolicy`** and the mentioned examples do not trigger any route processing. You have to send messages to the route to trigger processing. You can for example use another route to send messages or a [`producertemplate`](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/producertemplate.html). Every message you send to the route "travels" through the route and gets processed according to the route implementation.